# Rails 3 - collection_select - Understanding PROMPT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a form to allow a user to CRUD a project permission.

....

```
<% roles = Role.all %>
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, roles, :id, :name, :prompt => true %>
```

Problems with the above, while it renders:

1. If a value matches, it shows that in the dropdown as selected, which is good. Problem, is if a user is set as ADMIN. It's easy to use the dropdown to change the permission to something else, but not to CLEAR the permission...

Example... Select Drop Down:
 - Please Select
 - Admin
 - Member
 - Guest

If Admin is selected, Please Select never shows up.... How can I make an option show up to allow the user to remove the setting?

Any ideas? thx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:role_id, roles, :id, :name, {:include_blank => 'Please Select'} %>
```

See the [FormOptionsHelper docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) for more information

Answer (score 1):

```
<% roles = Role.all %>
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, roles, :id, :name, :prompt => (@user.admin? ? true : false) %>
```

does that help you?

you must be having a way to check if a user is admin / not.. use that condition in ternary operation to set the value of :prompt..

lemme know how it goes :)